# Facebook: App must be on whitelist

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-marketing-api

I'm using [Facebook Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/using-the-api). Starting from last week I get an error message when I try to send a request from my local machine.

The exact error I'm getting on my screen is the following:

```
RequestException in RequestException.php line 154:
(#3) App must be on whitelist
```

When I send a request from production server, the app is working fine and creates a campaign.

I went through all the possible settings in the app, to see if I'm able to configure it from there, but seems like the app is configured well.

App is also public:

> This app is public and available to all users

Appreciate any help or tips!

Comment: Sure you are using the same app id in both cases?

Comment: Yeap, but a week ago it suddenly started working...

Answer (score 0):

App suddenly started working without making any changes to code or configuration. Must be an Facebook issue...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when provide 'is_autobid' property to new campaign